# How to return Two Separate Array in PickerView in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uipickerview

I have created a `PickerView` in a `SegmentControl`, I am having two separate array FirstArray has `StringData`, Second Array has `NSNumber` data. I need to return both the array in order to return as `StringData`and Number in same row.

`For Example: First Array has : Ark,silk,temp etc, Second Array has 23,45,56 etc.`

If I return the first Array alone in `PickerView` it was returning String value, but I need both array to be displayed.I am done with displaying one array in picker view but don't know how to return two arrays. 
Code:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

   if (pickerView == EventsPickerView) {

   // case EventsPickerView:
        return EventArray.count

   }else {

    switch FabricSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {

    case 0:

        return globalConstants.ClassificationName.count
          //  return globalConstants.ClassificationName.count + globalConstants.ClassificationCount.count

    case 1:

        return globalConstants.ClassificationNameSecond.count





    default:
        return 1
    }
}
  //  return 1
}

 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

 if  (pickerView == EventsPickerView){

   // case EventsPickerView:
        return EventArray[row]

 }else {

    switch FabricSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {

    case 0:

        return globalConstants.ClassificationName[row] as? String




    case 1:

        return globalConstants.ClassificationNameSecond[row] as? String



    default:
        return "error occured"
    }

}

   // return "error occured"


}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if (pickerView == EventsPickerView){

        eventTextField.text = EventArray[row]
    }else {

        switch FabricSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {

        case 0:



                TypeOfSilkTextField.text = globalConstants.ClassificationName[row] as? String




        case 1:

              TypeOfSilkTextField.text = globalConstants.ClassificationNameSecond[row] as? String


        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

These are my array Names

`First Array :globalConstants.ClassificationName.count`

`SecondArray name :globalConstants.ClassificationCount.count`

Comment: If the data in the two arrays belong together why don’t you create a struct holding a string and a number or use a tuple and then have a single array of struct’s (or tuples)?

Comment: I will try this and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the 2 arrays are equal so return one of them here

```
return globalConstants.ClassificationName.count
```

//

In `titleForRow`

```
 return globalConstants.ClassificationName[row] as? String ?? "" + ( globalConstants.ClassificationCount[row] as? String ?? "" )
```

//

In  `didSelectRow`

```
TypeOfSilkTextField.text = globalConstants.ClassificationName[row] as? String ?? ""  + ( globalConstants.ClassificationCount[row] as? String ?? "" )
```

but it's better creating a struct to hold them as one unit

//

What makes sense to declare it like

```
 static let ClassificationName = ["value","value2"]
```

which will be inferred to array of strings `[String]`--- to `return ClassificationName[row]`

and

```
 static let ClassificationCount = [25,26]
```

which will be inferred to array of ints `[Int]`--- to `return "\(ClassificationCount[row])"`

Or be

```
 static let ClassificationCount = ["25","26"]
```

which will be inferred to array of Strings `[String]`--- to `return ClassificationCount[row]`

Comment: @V_rohit according to your question you attached the arrays as optionals Any

Answer (score 3):

You are returing NSNumber as String. That's why a nil value is returning.
Try converting NSNumber into String.